Fortify WebInspect finds a "Cross-Site Scripting: Reflected" vulnerability in ASP.NET MVC application on .NET 4.8
I'm using Fortify WebInspect v CE 24.2, Engine Version 4.33.00, and running it against an ASP.NET MVC application running on .NET 4.8. The application is about 13 years old.
We just switched to Fortify after using Veracode for some years. Veracode did not find this vulnerability.
The critical vulnerability is "Cross-Site Scripting: Reflected", CWE ID 80. In the test Fortify is passing this GET request. The url-encoded string is the number "57134".
GET /Workspace/DocumentSearch/%35%37%31%33%34 HTTP/1.1

The Controller action in question looks like this. It takes no parameters and ignores what Fortify is passing with no error:
public ActionResult DocumentSearch()

In the View I have a form coded like so; it posts back to another controller method with the same name:
@using (Html.BeginForm("DocumentSearch", "Workspace", FormMethod.Post))

The problem is, when the View renders, the bit of url-encoded text that Fortify adds to the query string, the number "57134", gets rendered in the form tag. That "57134" causes Fortify to label this a critical vulnerability per CWE ID 80:
<form action="/Workspace/DocumentSearch/57134" method="get">

My question is, why is this considered a critical vulnerability? I would understand a vulnerability if the site allowed a user to pass javascript (it doesn't; IIS returns a 500 error if any javascript is in the query string, the request never even gets as far as my web application). This extra bit of text added to the GET seems to be harmless.
Am I missing something? Is there a reason why this behavior should be labelled a critical vulnerability that leaves us vulnerable to Cross-Site Scripting? Can anyone provide an example of text appended to the query string that could be dangerous?
